# Oracle SQL , Split Date based on date overlap

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two tables EMPLOYEE , COMPANY

```
EMPID  START_DATE  END_DATE
123    1/05/2015   30/05/2015




COMPANYID   EMPID  START_DATE   END_DATE    SALARY
001          123    7/05/2015   15/05/2015  10000
```

I need to write a query so the result would be like this,

```
COMPANYID  EMPID   START_DATE  END_DATE   SALARY
001         123    1/05/2015   7/05/2015  0
001         123    7/05/2015   14/05/2015 10000
001         123    14/05/2015  30/05/2015 0
```

Similarly the query should work for all types of overlap - partial as well as complete. please help.

Comment: You should write the code that you tried so people can help you.

Comment: In the first table, how do you know what company the `EMPID` is for?  Your data structure seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to divide the timeline in parts, and split up all possibilities:

1. from employee start date to company start date in case they overlap
2. from employee start date to employee end date in case they do not overlap
3. from company start date to employee end date in case employee end date is before company end date
4. from compoany start date to company end date in case employee end date is after company end date
   etc.

Then you can join all queries together with "union all", which will result in a query like this (I might have forgotten some possibilities):

```
select c.companyid
, e.empid
, e.start_date
, e.end_date
, 0
from company c
,    employee e
where e.empid = c.empid
and   e.end_date <= c.start_date
union all
select c.companyid
, e.empid
, e.start_date
, c.start_date
, 0
from company c
,    employee e
where e.empid = c.empid
and  e.start_date <= c.start_date 
and  e.end_date > c.start_date
union all
select c.companyid
, e.empid
, c.start_date
, e.end_date
, c.salary
from company c
,    employee e
where e.empid = c.empid
and  e.start_date <= c.start_date 
and  e.end_date > c.start_date
and  e.end_date <= c.end_date
union all
select c.companyid
, e.empid
, c.start_date
, c.end_date
, c.salary
from company c
,    employee e
where e.empid = c.empid
and  e.start_date <= c.start_date 
and  e.end_date > c.end_date
union all
select c.companyid
, e.empid
, c.end_date
, e.end_date
, 0
from company c
,    employee e
where e.empid = c.empid
and  e.start_date <= c.start_date 
and  e.end_date > c.end_date
```

and the result will be:

```
companyid   empid   start_date  end_date    salary
1            123    5/1/2015    5/7/2015    0
1            123    5/7/2015    5/15/2015   10000
1            123    5/15/2015   5/30/2015   0
```